# Constant lambda expressions, shape of return data

Tags: python, arrays, lambda

A list of lambda expressions given to me (by [Sympy's lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html)), some explicitly depending on a variable `x`, some constant. I would like to evaluate those consistently with Numpy arrays.

When evaluating a lambda expression, e.g., `lambda x: 1.0 + x**2`, with a Numpy array `x`, the result will have the same shape as the array. If the expression happens to not explicitly contain `x` though, e.g., `g = lambda x: 1.0`, only a scalar is returned.

```
import numpy

f = [lambda x: 1.0 + x**2, lambda x: 1.0]

X = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])

print(f[0](X))
print(f[1](X))
```

returns

```
[  2.   5.  10.]
1.0
```

Is there a way to get the shapes of the output arguments consistent?

Comment: I know there is a better way, but just for the lolz: `g = lambda x: 1.0 * x/x`

Comment: @user667648: though that does bad things if `x` contains zeros. `1.0 + x*0` is safer.

Comment: @nneonneo: Yep... Good thing it was for the lolz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`ones_like`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones_like.html):

```
>>> X = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> def g(x): return numpy.ones_like(x)
>>> g(X)
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Note that this returns integers, not floats, because that was the input `dtype`; you could specify `dtype=float` or multiply by `1.0` if you prefer to always get floats out.

PS: It's a little odd to use a `lambda` and then immediately give it a name.  It's like wearing a mask but handing out business cards.

PPS: back before `ones_like` I tended to use `x*0+1` when I wanted something appropriately shaped.

Comment: I cannot use `ones_like` since I have no influence on the creation of the lambda expressions, but a wrapper that adds `0*x` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an array of ones:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.ones(3)
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

If you want to set scalars, it's easy to do so

```
g = lambda x: numpy.ones(shape=x.shape) * 2

g(X)
```

returns

```
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
```

So for an arbitrary array:

```
g = lambda x: numpy.ones(shape=x.shape) * 1

n = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

g(n) is

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem, just do:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 2, 3])

f = lambda x: 1.0 + x**2
print(f(X))

g = lambda x: np.ones(shape=(len(X),))
print(g(X))
```

Which prints:

```
[  2.   5.  10.]
[ 1.  1.  1.]
```

Notice that using `np.ones(shape=(len(X),))` is the same that using `np.ones_like(X)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ones_like`:

```
g = lambda x: np.ones_like(x) * 1.0
```

There's also this slightly hackier solution:

```
g = lambda x: 1.0 + (x*0)
```