# How to find negative elements in a multidimensional array? Use .any() .all() correctly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array `arr` with negative `double` elements. It is shaped `(1000,1000)`. As the elements are complex, we use `arr.real` to only evaluate the real part.

I first tried

```
for i in arr.real:
    if i < 0:
        print(i)
```

This gave the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However, if I try

```
for i in arr.real:
    if i.any() < 0:
        print(i)
```

or

```
for i in arr.real:
    if i.all() < 0:
        print(i)
```

there is no output. Nothing is printed, even though negative values do exist.

How do I rectify this? What am I misunderstanding?

EDIT:

```
for i in arr.real:
    print(i[i<0])
```

does work. However, how does one search for two conditions? For example,

```
i < 0 and i > -1e-12
```

Comment: The correct method would be `(i < 0).any()`. Similarly with `.all()`.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. Can you explain to me the difference? `(i < 0).any()` seems to output positive values

Comment: Well `i` is a slice of `arr` and as such `i.any()` won't really reflect your idea of finding negative elements in `arr`. That's why the second approach didn't work. The first one didn't work because `i` is still not a scalar.

Comment: `for i in arr: if (i < 0).any(): print(i)` This outputs positive values in the array (which originally is complex). What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you are dealing with arrays that have complex numbers? Well, then how would define positive values, as there would be real and imaginary parts? Then, compare both real and imag. parts and proceed based on how you define being *positive*.

Comment: @ali_m Thanks! `print(i[i < 0])` works perfectly. Clarifying question so I understand: Most of my elements are *very* small, on the order of `-9.43e-15`. Let's say I had two conditions, i.e `i<0` and `i>1e-14`. How do I print only the values that satisfy both conditions? `print(i[i<0] && i[i>1e-12])` doesn't work

Comment: @Divakar Yes, it should be `arr.real` above. Edited.
The above comment should read `for i in arr.real: if (i < 0).any(): print(i)`

Comment: @ali_m `-1e12`, not `1e12`

Comment: and , there is no && in python. Use **and**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `arr` is 2d, iteration gives you the rows, not the elements.

Make a sample array:

```
In [347]: arr=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)-10
In [348]: arr
Out[348]: 
array([[-10,  -9,  -8,  -7],
       [ -6,  -5,  -4,  -3],
       [ -2,  -1,   0,   1],
       [  2,   3,   4,   5]])
```

Iterate with some prints:

```
In [350]: for i in arr:
   print(i)
   print(i<0)
   print((i<0).any())
   .....:
```

result:

```
[-10  -9  -8  -7]
[ True  True  True  True]
True
[-6 -5 -4 -3]
[ True  True  True  True]
True
[-2 -1  0  1]
[ True  True False False]
True
[2 3 4 5]
[False False False False]
False
```

The `ValueError` results when you try to use that boolean array `np.array([True, True, False, False])` in an `if` statement.  Applying `all` or `any` to the array reduces it to one scalar True/False value, which works in the `if` statement.

You can apply the `negative` test to the whole array, and apply `all/any` to rows (or columns) - without iteration:

```
In [351]: arr<0
Out[351]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [352]: (arr<0).any(axis=1)
Out[352]: array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [353]: (arr<0).all(axis=1)
Out[353]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

to get the non-negative values in the array, you can use this boolean mask (or its negative):

```
In [354]: arr[arr>=0]
Out[354]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Because there are different numbers of valid values in each row it can't give you a 2d array.

But you can go back to iteration to get a list of values for each row.  Here I use a list comprehension to do the iteration.

```
In [355]: [a[a>=0] for a in arr]
Out[355]: 
[array([], dtype=int32),
 array([], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

Comment: For the two conditions I mention above, I think `(i[i<0 | i > some_arbitrary_value]) for i in arr` would work. Is there a standard way to do list comprehensions with several conditions?

Comment: As long as the expression produces the value you want it can be used in a list comprehension.  Use () to remove any ambiguity.  For more complex expressions, define a simple function that does the calculation: `[foo(x) for x in ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried lambda expressions?

```
for k in arr:
     print filter(lambda x: x < 0, k)
```

if your "array" is a dictionary with tuple keys you can use lambda alike this:

```
d = {(0,0):-3,(0,1):3,(0,2):-3.7,(0,3):0,
(1,0):30,(1,1):-12,(1,2):-0.1,(1,3):2.5,}

keys = filter(lambda x: d[x] < 0, [k for k in d])

print [d[keys[n]] for n in range(0,len(keys))]
```

perhaps to actually answer your question this will help,

```
import itertools as it
aK = it.product(range(0,len(arr)),range(0,len(arr)))

negKeys = filter(lambda x: arr[x[0]][x[1]] < 0, [k for k in ak])
negVals = [arr[k[0]][k[1]] for k in negKeys]
```

Comment: This outputs `<filter object at 0x107219400>`, etc.

Comment: Sry I had to fix that

Comment: It's the same output.

Comment: Hmm what is the type of Arr?
Also what is the [type(k) for k in arr] ?

Comment: `arr` is a numpy array

Comment: So have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253069/constant-lambda-expressions-shape-of-return-data It's funny the question looks like this http://numpychabi3.blogspot.com/2015/12/valueerror-of-lambda-expression-on.html as well

Comment: `numpy` arrays usually don't need `lambdas` or `itertools` to perform tests on the the whole array.

Answer (score -2):

It seems one way to do this is:

```
for row in arr.real:
    for i in row:
        if (i<0 and i<-1e-10):
            print(i)
```

Comment: To test and print individual elements of a 2d array you need either this nested loop, or iterate over the 1d `arr.ravel()` view.  But usually you don't want to iterate explicitly over an array.  That is slow.  Let `numpy` do the iteration in fast compiled code.